# Tkinter: Link an Entry Widget to a Button to a Function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and not to sure how to proceed. I am trying to link a function that I define to a entry widget that is activated by a button. but I can't figure out how to get the three to communicate to each other. I would like it to print as well as return to the script so that I can be used in another function. This is what I have so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk


def TestMath(x):
    calculate = x + 4
    print calculate
    return calculate


root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
value = entry.get()
number = int(value)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate")
calculation = TestMath(number)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Button( ... , command=TestMath)`

Comment: This question could've easily been researched on Google and even here on this site. Please look around and do research before posting simple questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button` calls function assigned to `command=` (it has to be "function name" without `()` and arguments - or lambda function)

`TestMath` assigns calculation to global variable `result` and other functions can have access to that value.

```
import Tkinter as tk


def TestMath():
    global result # to return calculation

    result = int(entry.get())
    result += 4

    print result

result = 0

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=TestMath)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Function called by button don't have to return value because there is no object which could receive that value.